# How can I simplify that part of code?

Tags: c#

I have a code:

```
    byte[][][] file = GetConfigData();

    if (file == null)
        return;

    int pages = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
    {   
        if (file[i] != null)
        {   
            for (j = 0; j < file[i].Length; j++)
            {   
                if (file[i][j] != null)
                {
                    pages++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I simplify it ?

Please, provide 2 versions:

1. for .net 2.0
2. for .net 3.5 (linq)

Comment: What version of the framework? I'm sure someone will come up with a LINQ-One-Liner. ;)

Comment: Bobby, thanks for correction. I added it in a question.

Comment: you can use LINQ for .NET 2.0 as long as the compiler is 3.0+ so what do you need? examples that can run on 2.0 or examples that can compile with the 2.0C# compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean 'how can I make it easier to understand', then my number one suggestion would be to use more meaningful variable names.

It will be longer but simpler.

You could also use 'foreach' instead of 'for' - that would lose some of the index variables anyway.

And finally you could use some hairy linq line to do it all in a functional style, but that won't be 'simpler' in any beginner's sense.

Comment: Will Dean, I mean: i don't like checks for null values in that code so _maybe_ there is a better way to get pages variable without null checks ?

Comment: If you can guarantee that `GetConfigData()` will never return nulls at any level of the array then you can drop the null checks - otherwise they should stay. Do you control `GetConfigData()`?

Comment: Rup, no, I don't control GetConfigData(). I get that byte array from a device via C++ module (i use pinvoke). So I can't guarantee it'll have no data, some data, full data, uncomplete data ...

Comment: rather subjective isn't it: "but that won't be 'simpler' in any beginner's sense" what if the beginner came from say FP? What's so hairy about LINQ any way?

Comment: Well, what if they came from a culture with only 26 words, each with only one letter?  Then they'd find my suggestion about variable names confusing.  It's all subjective at some level, if you can invent an entirely hypothetical audience to be confused... :-)

Comment: not hypothetical at all :) the first language taught at CS where I studied is actually is OCaml variant

Comment: Right, and you went into your first OCaml lecture having never written any imperative software before?

Answer (score 5):

I am not used to .NET 2.0 but I can provide you some .NET 3.5 Linq query.

Here it is:

```
pages = (from i in file
         where i != null
         from j in i
         where j != null
         select j).Count();
```

But as you can see and as Will Dean said, even if it is simpler it will not automatically make it easier to understand.
I would add that when you go too far in code simplification, you may also go farer in code unreadability.

I prefer meaningful and easy to read code to powerfull and shorter code because with time, hardware improve, so a well written and easy to read code will go faster and will stay easy to maintain, but a shorter and unreadable code will stay unreadable.

Comment: thanks for your answer, anyway. And, I agree, Will Dean is right.

Comment: Your code will run on .NET 2.0 runtime (it will need a C#3.0 compiler of cause)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my shot at rewritting your code. I strugled with the naming of the variables since I basically don't know what the array represents but change the names to something that makes sense in your domain and I'd say this is a lot easier to read than the original :)

```
byte[][][] file = GetConfigData();

if (file == null)
  return;

var existingFiles = files.Where(file => files != null);
var pages = existingFiles.Count(subFile => subFile != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[][][] files = new byte[][][]
    {
        new byte[][] { new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2 }, null, new byte[] { 0x3, 0x4 } },
        new byte[][] { null, new byte[] { 0x5, 0x6 }, new byte[] { 0x7, 0x8 } },
        new byte[][] { null, null, new byte[] { 0x9, 0x10 } },
        new byte[][] { null, null, null },
    };

    var pages = Test(files); // 5
}

static int Test(byte[][][] files)
{
    return files.SelectMany(f => f).Count(b => b != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `GetConfigData` to return something other than byte arrays? I'm guessing a Dictionary would be easier to use.

Code is easier to manage if you use the `continue` keyword to reduce the amount of nesting in it, because using `continue` explicitly says to the reader **in this case we should skip to the next iteration**.

You can't remove the null checks unless you know the underlying data will always have a value.

```
byte[][][] file = GetConfigData();

if (file == null)
    return;

int pages = 0;
foreach (var xxx in file)
{
    if (xxx == null)
        continue;
    foreach (var yyy in xxx)
    {
        if (yyy == null)
            continue;

        pages++;
    }
}
```

I just used `xxx` and `yyy` as placeholder names for the variables because I'm not sure what they represent.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change GetConfigData().